# "First Aid found corruption that needs to be repaired"

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, disk-utility, startup, recovery

I was trying to re-install Windows through Bootcamp, and it was stuck at partitioning. I quit Bootcamp, and now in the disk utility I get this error, even when in recovery mode:

> First Aid found corruption that needs to be repaired. To repair the startup volume, run First Aid from Recovery

I am backing it up right now, but how can I fix this? It's my school computer with important stuff, so any help is appreciated. It's a MacBook Pro (Retina, Late 2013) running macOS Sierra.

Comment: You need to provide us with more info. What model of MacBook are your running? What version of macOS is installed? And, what kind of drive does the MacBook have: SSD v HDD v Fusion/Hybrid?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed my own problem:

I went into internet recovery mode (Cmd+Option+R) on startup and was able to repair the disk from disk utility inside of internet recovery. I guess it was cause recovery was on the disk I was trying to fix.

Answer (score 2):

One key point that was left out - you have to mount the disk when using disk utility in recovery mode

Full solution:

1. Power down
2. Restart in internet recovery mode (cmd + opt + R)
3. Select disk utility
4. Select the SSD
5. Click “mount”
6. Run first aid
7. Restart

I was trying without mounting the disk. First Aid would appear to run like normal, but didn’t find anything to correct. Mounting the disk first enables First Aid to find and repair the issues.

Comment: Mounting the disk before running First Aid was the missing step for me, thanks!